# embed in html page twitter timelines. css mod

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-timeline

I have embedded a twitter timeline in a html page with this javascript code:

```
<a class="twitter-grid" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/timelines/539487832448843776">National Park Tweets</a> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Here is the page:    `http://goo.gl/E4RON8`

[image]

The problem is that I would have this effect:
[image]

I have the correct visualization if I set zoom to +200% in Chrome.

Can you help me to set the correct css rules?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you didn't set the width properly. Try to add below CSS changes,

- `width=100%` in class `"entryContent"` - This will expand the list items as needed.
- `max-width=100%` in class `"page-template-page-fullwidth-php .col-md-8"`-this will over-ride existing max-width.